# Mysql delete all records with same ID if not finished

Tags: mysql

Let me explain my problem a little bit, this is my table

```
Statuses           | RESPONSEOID

Solicita Despacho   4432
Despachado          4432
En Camino           4432
En el Lugar         4432
Terminado           4432
Finalizado          4432
Solicita Despacho   0224
Despachado          0224
En el Lugar         0224
Solicita Despacho   5585
Despachado          5585
En Camino           5585
En el Lugar         5585
En el Lugar         5585
Terminado           5585
Finalizado          5585
Solicita Despacho   1824
Despachado          1824
En Camino           1824
En el Lugar         1824
Solicita Despacho   4688
Terminado           4688
Finalizado          4688
Solicita Despacho   1430
Despachado          1430
Terminado           1430
Finalizado          1430
```

So this is a table that contains EVENTS (For example the ID 4432 is only one event with many statuses)

With this in my mind i need to 2 solve a problems,

1) i have to delete all events (all statuses and rows included) that does not have the status Finalizado (Finished)

2)I have to delete all events (all statuses and rows included) that have duplicate statuses

So in the example above i will have to delete all the records with responseoid = 0224 and 1824 for problem one and responseoid = 5585 for problem two

But consider that the table haves 11500000 rows aprox.

i do not care is this is posible with one or two querys

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks that first duplicate needs to be deleted, then final.. status

Comment: thanks for the input, but i need to know how to do it. Greeting

Comment: It would be easier if you put this on sql fiddle

Comment: @anguswild please clarify if you want ALL duplicates deleted? or, do you maybe wish for one with the highest/lowest ID preserved?

Comment: i want to delete the COMPLETE Event (Considering that an event is all the rows whit the same responseoid) when statuses have one o more duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first task, try this query -

```
DELETE t1
  FROM table t1
  JOIN (SELECT RESPONSEOID FROM table
          GROUP BY RESPONSEOID
          HAVING(COUNT(IF(Statuses = 'Finalizado', 1, null))) = 0
       ) t2
    ON t1.RESPONSEOID = t2.RESPONSEOID;
```

For the second one, you should repopulate table -

```
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table;
```

If there was an ID field, it would be possible to remove duplicates without repopulating.

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to bring first list of id having value of Finalizado and use **NOT IN** to delete other ids

```
 delete from tableName where RESPONSEOID NOT IN (select a.ids from 
(select RESPONSEOID as ids from tableName where Statuses='Finalizado' 
) a)
```

2) to delete duplicate

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX all_columns_uq
    (RESPONSEOID, Statuses) ;
```

**NOTE :** try this first on temp table make sure all is correct than use on original table

Comment: @Mohtisham see carefully I get the id of Finalizado and do not delete same ids. so It will no delete same id with different status :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it through query

1. Answer to your 1st part

   ```
   delete from table 
   where statuses NOT IN ('Finalizado')
   ```
2. Answer to you 2nd part is: add unique constraint to fields it will delete all duplicated entries like:

   ```
   ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table
       ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (statuees);   // you can pass multiple fields name comma-separated
   ```

Comment: your first query also delete all ids. from example he need this 4432 id with all other status

Answer (score 0):

Keep the highest ID:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `users` t1, `users` t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
```

Keeping the lowest ID:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `users` t1, `users` t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
```